# Read file and get certain value from each line of file

Tags: python, regex, file-io, for-loop

I'm stuck on a particular point on something, I'm hoping you guys could perhaps suggest a better method.

For each line of file I'm reading I want to get the nth word of the line, store this and print them on a single line.

I have the following code:

```
import os

p = './output.txt'

word_line = ' '

myfile = open(p, 'r')
for words in myfile.readlines()[1:]: # I remove the first line because I don't want it
    current_word = words.strip().split(' ')[4]
    word_line += current_word
    print word_line
myfile.close()
```

The file it reads looks like this:

```
1 abc-abc.abc (1235456) [AS100] bla 123 etc
2 abc-abc.abc (1235456) [AS10] bla 123 etc
3 abc-abc.abc (1235456) [AS1] bla 123 etc
4 abc-abc.abc (1235456) [AS56] bla 123 etc
5 abc-abc.abc (1235456) [AS8] bla 123 etc
6 abc-abc.abc (1235456) [AS200] bla 123 etc
etc
```

My current code outputs the following:

```
[AS100][AS10][AS1][AS56][AS8][AS200]
```

Only problem is, it is not always fixed as the 4th value of the line, as sometimes it appears as 5th, etc or not at all.

I'm currently trying out:

```
if re.match("[AS", words):
    f_word = re.match(".*[(.*)",words)
```

This isn't working out, I'm trying to see if in the current line it finds an open "[" If it does to display the content of it before the closing "]. Move on to the new line and keep on doing this.

Eventually have the following desired output:

```
AS100 AS10 AS1 AS56 AS8 AS200
```

I could really use some advise on this. Thanks

EDIT:

```
m = re.search(r'\[AS(.*?)]', words)
if m:
    f_word += ' ' + m.group(1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` is a special character in regular expressions and denotes the start of a character class.  Escape it.

```
m = re.search(r'\[AS(.*?)]', words)
if m:
    f_word = m.group(1)
```

Comment: f_word does that store up all the found value, does it concatenate the found value at the end so that it matches the output I have specified above? When I incorperate this into my script with the loop, it doesn't show all found in a single line. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for replying

Comment: Ah, f_word += m.group(1) did the job for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: The format is not right though, it adds everything with no space.

Comment: @chino try f_word += ' ' + m.group(1)